# Content approval by roles

Tags: 7, nodes, workflows, workbench

here is my question:

I need to implement a content approval process, my client wants content to go through an approval process before being published.

I need to create 3 administrative roles, like Content Editors, Content Publishers and Super Admins.

Content Editors can edit content, but not publish it. Content Publishers can edit and publish content (which includes approving/rejecting any changes made Content Editors). Super Admins would have access to everything in Drupal 7.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What version of Drupal?

Comment: Drupal 7 version

Answer (score 4):

[Workbench](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench) is a great way to do this if you are OK with installing another module.

Workbench allows you to add moderation states. By default it gives you 'draft', 'published', and 'needs review'. (Drupal 8 also has "archived"). There is also a set of transitions that go with these states (ie, draft -> needs review)

For the three roles you described above, I would give the Content Editors the states to move from published -> new draft, draft -> needs review, needs review-> draft. Content Publishers would have access to all transitions, and super admins could override workflow entirely. This would produce the result you are looking for (and is what we commonly use with clients who don't need something more complicated).

D7 workbench can be a little confusing (very powerful means there's lots to configure!), but here's a good quickstart guide:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8nqWLrxH_4M

EDIT: As the OP points out, [Drafty](https://www.drupal.org/project/drafty) is a dependency for Workbench Moderation, which is needed for the above described solution. Drafty is no longer supported under Drupal' security advisory policy.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I was trying to installed it but It requires one module call Drafty that it's not supported for drupal security advisory and It could have some vulnerabilities. I can not take that risk because my client is very strict with the site's security.

Comment: I don't know how you installed it, but drafty is not a dependency. You should only need the following two modules at most: https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench
https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation
There may be guides out there that suggest using other modules, but that's all you really need.

Comment: when I tried to install workbech moderation depended on Drafty, when I wanted to enable the module didsn't let me do it if I didn't have Drafty module installed it

Comment: I apologize, I stand corrected. Drafty is indeed a dependency in D7! That's a real bugger. There's no other equivalent to this functionality that I'm aware of that is also supported under the Drupal security advisory.